# what is the point to have padding 2px top and bottom

Tags: html, css

In declaration "#message a" I have a style padding that looks like this

```
padding: 2px 15px;
```

so what is the point to have padding top and bottom when there is no change in appearance. Even if I change padding to

```
"padding: 100px 15px;"
```

this 100px doesn't make any change in appearance. This 15px is correct and make some change in appearance.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Chapter 3: Expandable Rows</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body 
{
   margin:5px;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: small;
   text-align: center;
   width: 768px;
}

#register 
{ 
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
color: #690;
background: #BDDB62;
}

#register a 
{
text-decoration: none;
color: #360;
}

#reg 
{
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 8px 14px;
}

#find 
{
float: right;
margin: 0;
padding: 8px 14px;
} 

#message 
{
    clear:both;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:110%;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
    background: #92B91C;
}


#message p 
{
margin: 0;
padding: 8px 14px;
}

#message strong 
{
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#message a 
{
margin: 0 0 0 6px;
padding: 2px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: normal;
color: #fff;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<ul id="register">
    <li id="reg">Not registered? <a href="#">Register</a> now!</li>
    <li id="find"><a href="#">Find a store</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="message">
    <p><strong>Special this week:</strong> $2 shipping on all orders! <a 
 href="#">LEARN MORE</a></p>
</div>`enter code here`
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you narrow down your code to just show the issue you're talking about, and save a JSFiddle out of it (on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)) please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The anchor tag is an inline element so it will not display vertical padding.

> While padding can be applied to all sides of an inline element, only
>   left and right padding will have an effect on surrounding content.

To see the vertical padding applied change the `a` to `display:inline-block`.

```
#message a{
   padding: 2px 15px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/sL7kT/

[See this article on how CSS properties are applied to inline elements](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/).

Answer (score 1):

Simply `a` tag cannot be adjusted by width, height , padding etc..

Add: `display: inline-block;` to make anchor inline block.

```
#message a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 100px 10px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eAxsh/

Answer (score 0):

you have your a tag in paragraph tag so its abide to the line height of its parents which is your paragraph tag.. so if you give the vertical padding it wont applyl.. rather use inline-block on your a tag